# is there an event to detect a class attribute change on a template element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

If you use a framework such as bootstrap, you know that an element classes change depending on actions or viewport size...

Is there an event in Angular that allows us to detect when the classes of an element change?

For example, having a bootstrap navbar, each time it has `show` class in its class list I want to `console.log("show")`, and each time it doesn't have `show` class in its class list I want to `console.log("hide")`. In other words, I want to subscribe to the class change of the element.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493998/angular-2-change-class-on-condition

Comment: How classes are added or removed from your element, by angular or by using basic javascript and dom manipulation?

Comment: @RezaRahmati they are added and removed by Bootstrap (in jQuery)

Comment: @EddyG then I guess there is no way to handle it in angular

Answer (score -1):

You could detect a class change by using EventEmitter to `emit` the change. You'll need to `subscribe` to it before emitting. See the following example, hope that helps:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p [ngClass]="{ active: active }">
      The active text
    </p>
    <button (click)="isActive($event)">change class</button>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .active {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  `]
})

export class AppComponent {
  active = false;
  activate: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  isActive(event) {
    this.active = !this.active;
    this.activate.emit(this.active);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activate.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('active: ' + data);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to detect it using the click event or an alternative event. I want to detect it on the element itself.

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in event in angular that gives you info about a component's class change. I imagine you'll have to build that mechanism yourself. You could have a child component that emits 'classChanged' along with the class that changed (eg. 'show'). Then in the parent component, you can handle that via a listener function.